# Send message has been delivering successfully, But when i'm trying to get messages from agent no messages be presented in agent

Tags: glassfish, jms, openmq

I'm new to JMS+OPenMq + Glassfish , please give me up by make successful send message and receive  messages....

I have  created two different servlet programs and i have deployed in galssfish server....Here i'm sending message successfully , but consumer has not able to consuming messages ......

producer :

```
          Properties p = new Properties(); 
                               p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        p.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "iiop://localhost:3700");
        InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(p);
        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("jms/HQTapicConnectionFactory");
        Topic topic = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup("jms/HqDestTopic");
        System.out.println(topic.getTopicName());
                    TopicConnection connection =  (TopicConnection) connectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
                    System.out.println(connection.toString());
        TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  //createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        TopicPublisher publisher = session.createPublisher(topic);
        ObjectMessage message = session.createObjectMessage();
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeList= new ArrayList<Employee>();
        Employee employee  = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              employee =  new Employee();
             employee.setEmpid((100+i));
             employee.setName("devid"+i);
             employeeList.add(employee);
        }
       System.out.println(employeeList.size());
        message.setObject(employeeList);
        publisher.send(message);
```

Consumer:

public void onMessage(Message message){

```
  ObjectMessage objectMessage= (ObjectMessage) message;

try{

  System.out.println("Received the following message: ");
  Object object = objectMessage.getObject(); 

  if(object  instanceof ArrayList){
      ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList)object;
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
          Object object1 = arrayList.get(i); 
         if(object1  instanceof Employee){
          Employee employee = (Employee)object1;
          System.out.println(employee.getEmpid());
          System.out.println(employee.getName());
             System.out.println();
         }
    }
  }

}
catch (JMSException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I'm not able to receiving messages ,

Please help me to proper configure for broker  in glassfish server.

,...appreciate for your replay

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer is in a servlet, it will only catch the messages which are sent in the same moment of time (quite unlikely) - you are using **topics** which do not buffer by default.

Either use **queues** (instead of topics) or write a stand-alone program which is permanently running (and thus listening/eceiving). Normally topic listeners do not make much sense in a servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your replay .....
I have successfully executed  standalone application for 2 models (P-TO-P and Pub/Sub). But i want to implement both models (P-to-P and pub/sub ) in my applications(both applications flows by using servlet(Spring MVC))... For that purpose i have implemented pub/sub in servlet example servlet....plz can you help in this case...And Can you provide documentation(URL) for IMQ BROKER CONFIGURATION......